# Filter a List of Objects Based on A Different List of Objects with Linq

Tags: c#, linq, filtering

I currently have two types of Lists: List (named LintMessages) and List (named FilterList).

```
PCMessages Properties:
    public string filename { get; set; }
    public int linenumber { get; set; }
    public string messagetype { get; set; }
    public int messagecode { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string evaluated { get; set; }
    public string comment { get; set; }

Filter Properties:
    public bool applied { get; set; }
    public string messagetype { get; set; }
    public int messagecode { get; set; }
    public string evaluated { get; set; }
    public string filename { get; set; }
```

The goal is to exclude PCMessages from LintMessages that fit the criteria of any applied Filter and store them in List FiltLintMessages.  For example, if FilterList contains two filters:

```
Filter1 Properties:
    applied = true;
    messagetype = Warning;
Filter2 Properties:
    applied = true;
    messagecode = 12;
    evaluated = "WIP";
```

Then I wish to create a List FiltLintMessages from LintMessages that excludes any entries where messagetype contains "Warning" or where messagecode=12 or where evaluated contains "WIP".

Code at time of writing:

```
FiltLintMessages = (from mess in LintMessages
                    from filt in FilterList
                    where !mess.evaluated.Contains(filt.evaluated)
                         && !mess.filename.Contains(filt.filename) 
                         && mess.messagecode != filt.messagecode
                         && !mess.messagetype.Contains(filt.messagetype)
                    select mess).ToList();
```

Any help would be appreciated.

/* Edited to work off of gaearon's suggested solution. Stepping through with debugger shows that this is the only relevant code to the problem. The correct items are in each list coming up to this block and on the assignment to FiltLintMessages, two separate filters (exclude messagetype "Warning" and messagecode = 10, both applied) only excludes messagecode=10 PCMessages as it is the last applied filter in the list (tested with several instances of multiple filters).  However, the code works with a *single* applied filter excluding both messagetype = "Warning" and messagecode = 10.  Uploading any more of the code would not help and would bog down the post even more (the program is getting quite large). */

```
IEnumerable<PCMessage> messages = LintMessages;

foreach (LintMessageFilter filter in FilterList.Where(f => f.applied))
{
    messages = messages.Where(
               m => !m.evaluated.Contains(filter.evaluated)
                       && !m.filename.Contains(filter.filename)
                       && m.messagecode != filter.messagecode
                       && !m.messagetype.Contains(filter.messagetype)
                );
}

FiltLintMessages = messages.ToList(); //FiltLintMessages already initialized
```

Comment: I think your `messagetype` and `messagecode` should be nullable, because otherwise there's no way to tell if they are initialized or just set to the default values.

Comment: Edited default properties of PCMessages so that default values of Filters will never overlap and provide a false positive.

Comment: You should use nullable types instead of non-trivial default values. Such as `int?` and `MessageType?` (if `MessageType` is enum). Then, in filtering code, check for nullity.

Comment: @Bandoth: instead of writing `(something == false)` you should write `(!something)` (“not something”). This is C# idiom and it's hard to read code otherwise.

Comment: @gaearon: Haha, I have a couple friends who would beg to differ.  I'll evaluate the rest of my code to see if nullable types would be worth adding all the checks for values before using them, but it seems like it would make things quite a bit more explicit.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Bandoth: I posted this as a question in case your friends don't mind :-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6336735/if-condition-vs-if-condition-false-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would apply each `applied` filter to the sequence in order.

```
IEnumerable<PCMessages> messages = LintMessages;

foreach (var filterIter in FilterList.Where(f => f.applied)) {
    var filter = filterIter; // capture current filter
    messages = messages.Where (m =>
                   !m.evaluated.Contains (filter.evaluated)
                   && !m.filename.Contains (filter.filename)
                   && m.messagecode != filter.messagecode
                   && !m.messagetype.Contains (filter.messagetype)
    );
}

var FiltLintMessages = messages.ToList ();
```

Comment: Strange.  Using this method seems to work with any single applied filter, but applying multiple filters seems to only use the last applied one in the FilterList.

Comment: @Bandoth: all right, you got me. Because `Where` is evaluated only on its enumeration, apparently `filter` was always the last filter used. You need to capture current filter inside of `foreach` and use it for filtering.

Comment: @gaearon: Thank you very much.  Works beautifully.

Comment: @Bandoth: if the answer helped you, please don't hesitate to upvote it. You can do so by pressing the up button next to it. Thanks.