# Any references / MSDN tutorials to show support for either "if (!condition)" or "if (condition == false)"?

Tags: c#, coding-style, if-statement, conditional-statements, msdn

**For those who misread the question: let's pretend [we're on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aV).**
**I'm not looking for “the right way”, I'm looking for verifiable references to support either side.**

(Please read to the end)

#### The Context

In a comment on a different thread, a person said *his friends would beg to differ* with my opinion on whether

```
if (!condition)
```

or

```
if (condition == false)
```

is preferred in C#.

As much as I was sure I know how to do the Right Thing™, I was unable to find any evidence my opinion is official in neither C# coding nor design guidelines.

#### The Question

Is there anything **substantial** to show in support of either side, apart from the common sense?

(a **paragraph in a widely admired book** or any document **hosted at `microsoft.com`** that **uses or prescribes either style** over another will **answer the question**)

Comment: If you are using both bool? and bool types then == false makes the code more uniform.

Comment: I suspect the answers you get will be quite similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245666/not-keyword-vs-false-when-checking-for-false-boolean-condition. There are good points to be made re: naming the variable. `if (!Node.HasChildren)` reads more naturally than `if (Node.HasChildren == false)`.

Comment: @iterationx: very cool observation although it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @closers: I edited the title, should be more clear now.

Comment: The answer is "no" you aren't going to find any official document saying that one is better than the other.  Just lots of opinions.

Comment: @Robert: there are lots of tutorials in MSDN. Links to a couple of them using one style over another will answer the question.

Comment: @gaearom: how do you mean 'substantional'? I mean, is this an English word?

Comment: @p.campbell: as stated in the answer, any MSDN document that prescribes or uses one style over another is substantial.

Comment: You will see both on MSDN.  I worked at MS and wrote some of those samples... Promise there is no official guideline on this.

Comment: @Robert: I actually thought there is some kind of detailed guideline for MSDN samples. Glad you pointed this out. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if (!condition)` and `if (condition)` are preferred over `if (condition == false)` and `if (condition == true)` because the former is just as readable and less verbose.

Bottom section of page 13 of [C# Coding Standards for .NET](http://se.inf.ethz.ch/old/teaching/ss2007/251-0290-00/project/CSharpCodingStandards.pdf) created by [Lance Hunt](http://weblogs.asp.net/lhunt/) says:

> Avoid evaluating Boolean conditions against true or false.

```
// Bad! 
if (isValid == true) 
{ ... } 
// Good! 
if (isValid) 
{ ... }
```

However it is not by any means official and it doesn't come from Microsoft.

Comment: Agreeing, `condition == false` mostly is an indication of little meaningful naming of variables.

Comment: doesn't actually answer the question

Comment: @Bala: can you confirm it with a **verifiable reference**? This is what question is about.

Comment: @gaearon see page 13 bottom section of http://se.inf.ethz.ch/old/teaching/ss2007/251-0290-00/project/CSharpCodingStandards.pdf sorry it's some random coding standards doc that came up top in search results but essentially it all comes down to the coding standards that your organization is following. There is no strict right/wrong way in this matter.

Comment: @Bala: thanks for the reference. Kind of what I was looking for, however it's not from Microsoft which makes it not as useful. I understand there is no strict way, I was just wondering if there are *official* recommendations (as there are for naming, spacing, etc).

Comment: There are also no official guidelines on spacing

Comment: @Robert: there are (they are internal but still come from Microsoft, hence official). http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2005/01/26/361363.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I use if (condition == false) if the condition being false is an extreme edge case - it brings attention to that fact for me.

Comment: Please re-read the question, this is not what is being asked.